# php server can not open .php file in some cases like if i add for loop for example

Tags: php

This code will work.

```
<?php 

    print "sd\n"

?>
```

BUT this is not working.

```
<?php 
for(;;){
}
    print "sd\n"

?>
```

so my server works only with some functions like "print","print_r", but other functions does not working
This page isn’t working

192.168.43.253 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: the 2nd snippet doesn't have a closing semi-colon. I know the 1st doesn't either but it is only important in the 2nd

Comment: No, it's not...? Why would a semi-colon help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Error 500 comes when there is something wrong with server and server cannot be specific about the problem. You must always check for server logs for the actual problem.

In your case here , the error is generated because server is trapped inside an infinite loop.

```
for( ; ; )
```

will have condition always true and the loop will not terminate and server will be trapped in processing it.
**And you're missing ';' in your second snippet with print line.**( that's not the actual cause of problem though)

> For loop shall always be used with predetermined number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the `for` loop wrong.

Here's the right way:

```
<?php 
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    print "sd\n";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Why do you increment the x-variable twice? There is no reason to have it inside the for-loop as well.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Good catch. Sorry about that, wrote it fast on my phone.